# Case statement with TComponent in Delphi

Tags: delphi

There are a way to do a case statement with Tcomponent?, i mean:

```
begin
  case Form1.Components[i] of
    TEdit: //do something;
    TMenuItem: //Do Something;
    TButton: //Do Somtehing;
  end;
end;
```

I known can do this:

```
if (Form1.components[i] is TEdit) then
...
```

but just i want to known if possible with case statement.

Regards.

Comment: `case x of TObject: ....; TPersistentObject ...; TComponent: ...; TWinControl: ....; end;` - which branch should compiler take if you pass `TButton` as x ???

Comment: @Arioch'The The first one, of course.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/E2001_Ordinal_type_required_%28Delphi%29

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't think so. In `record` declarations for example `case` takes every matching part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Case statements support only [ordinal types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/E2001_Ordinal_type_required_(Delphi)). Ordinal types are the predefined types Integer, Char, WideChar, Boolean, and declared enumerated types, so that excludes classes, strings and even floating point numbers.

[The documentation says](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Case_Statements):

> **Case Statements**
>
> The case statement may provide a readable alternative to deeply nested
>   if conditionals. A case statement has the form:
>
> ```
> case selectorExpression of
>   caseList1: statement1;
>    ...
>   caseListn: statementn;
> end
> ```
>
> where *selectorExpression* is any expression of an ordinal type
>   smaller than 32 bits (string types and ordinals larger than 32 bits
>   are invalid) ....

Of course there are ways around this, like building a list of componentclasses or componentnames, and doing a case on the index of the component in that list, but they are limited (can't easily use a TCustomEdit to match TEdit, TMemo and others, when matching by string). So to me, the a normal if is the best way to write this.

Answer (score 8):

```
Case IndexStr(Form1.Components[i].classname, ['TEdit', 'TButton', 'TmenuItem', 'etc...']) of 
  0: ..code..;                   // TEdit
  1: ..code..;                   // TButton
  2: ..code..;                   // TMenuItem
 -1: ShowMessage('Not Present'); // not present in array
else
  ShowMessage('Default Option'); // present, but not handled above
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Case statements require an enumeration type, which a class type is not.

Comment: Thanks you @UweRaabe

Comment: **Ordinal** (!) type